# При попытке загрузить json в gitHubPages ошибка 404

Tags: javascript, json

Когда открываю сайт через live server в vs code всё работает, json загружается и создает нужную таблицу с элементами. Но когда я залил всё на github, страница gitРubPages выдаёт мне ошибку 404.

Запрос Json

```
 fetch("../../utils/applicant-information.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => this.createTemplate(json));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы в браузере открывали данный адрес?

Answer (score 0):

Поместите файлы json и скрипт с запросом в одно место, в моём случае я поместил их в корень проекта где index.html. Так же в самом запросе пишите только так name.json без пути.